# httpservice - resultEvent

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I'm working on a AIR application.
To load a form I need to execute several httpservice to load data from mysql database.
All works well, but as httpservice is asynchrous, I'd to know if all ResultEvent is good before to show the window.
All services are send in preinitialize phase, but how to know if all send result?
Thanks for helping

Comment: Read the [faq] please. Post what you tried here. If you haven't tried anything, try something first. Don't expect us to do your work for you

Comment: I read the faq and I test several solution with no succes. But now I found a solution.

Comment: @Flex60460 Please either reword this into a real question, and post your solution, or delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my window, I add enable property like that:

```
 enabled="{bload==6}"
```

Because to load my form, I must load 6 httpservice.

I declare a bindable variable

```
[Bindable] private var bload:int=6;
```

Before to launch all my httpservice I do `bload = 0;`

So my window is enable even if all httpservice send result. because in each resultEvent I do

```
bload++;
```